# PHP PDO Order ASC

Tags: php, sql

I have this code as my function of getting the list, however with the ORDER BY code it doesnt work (doesn't return anything). How do i go about ordering it? I have looked at other peoples work on how o do it but i can't get it to work.

```
<?php
function getGenericList($conn, $limit) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `jobs_current` LIMIT ".$limit." ORDER BY `jobs_current`.`school` ASC";
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $count = $query->rowCount();
    if($count == 0){
        return '<td class="td1"></td><td class="td2" style="color: red;">Sorry, there doesnt seem to be any results!</td><td class="td3"></td>';
    }
    $end = "";
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {

        $end = $end.'<tr class="hoverOver"><td class="td1"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['school'].'</a></td>';
        $end = $end.'<td class="td2"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['job_type'].'</a></td>';
        $end = $end.'<td class="td3"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['location'].'</a></td></tr>';

    }return $end;
}
?>
```

Why doesn't it just return the rows in order defined? I generated the query using phpmyadmin so i don't understand why it doesnt work.

Comment: You are running the same query twice. and both times it's prone to SQL injection

Comment: @YourCommonSense the SQL injection comment is getting old - we need some new stuff to annoy those noobs!

Comment: @YourCommonSense Care to explain how its prone to SQL injection?

Comment: @Deckerz if some user somehow finds out how to manipulate your `$limit` variable s/he can do bad things to your database (drop table, drop database, and so on..). that's why you should use parameters: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: @low_rents Hi, yes i see with what you can see it is, however at the moment it is hardcoded somewhere else atm. Thank you for the information though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You query syntax is wrong, the correct way to write this is first ORDER and then LIMIT :

```
"SELECT * FROM `jobs_current` ORDER BY `jobs_current`.`school` ASC LIMIT ".$limit.""
```

Comment: Thanks i didn't realise i had made that mistake!